# argument of type "double" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *"

Tags: c

I am using a function to create an array of structures for certain information. I get this error and I'm guessing that the `char buf[]` variable is the one causing the error.

Is there a way I can convert the `buf` variable in order for it to be compatible with the `strsub` function? The last `strsub` call is the one that is giving me the error.

The salary is a `double` variable and the `buf` is a `char[]`.

```
void strsub(char buf[], char sub[], int start, int end) {
int i, j;
double x;

for (j = 0, i = start; i <= end; i++, j++) {
    sub[j] = buf[i];
}
sub[j] = '\0';

while (!feof(fp)) {
    fgets(buf, MAX, fp);
    strsub(buf, dataArray[i].first, 0, 6);
    strsub(buf, dataArray[i].initial, 8, 8);
    strsub(buf, dataArray[i].last, 10, 18);
    strsub(buf, dataArray[i].street, 20, 35);
    strsub(buf, dataArray[i].city, 37, 47);
    strsub(buf, dataArray[i].state, 49, 50);
    strsub(buf, dataArray[i].zip, 52, 56);
    strsub(buf, dataArray[i].age, 58, 59);
    strsub(buf, dataArray[i].sex, 61, 61);
    strsub(buf, dataArray[i].tenure, 63, 63);
    strsub(buf, dataArray[i].salary, 65, 69);




}
}
```

Comment: Show us where char buf[] is declared. Also, can you post the whole error message?

Comment: If the last call of `strsub` is the issue, my guess would be that `dataArray[i].salary` is a double. 
Edit: it seems that was stated in the question..

Comment: @uberwulu That is exactly what I am doing: learning. Why would I be inquiring about a topic if I was not learning it?

Comment: @Pahjay: Yes, but this question shows such low understanding of the C language that you really need to read a tutorial or ask a teacher.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/12711

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass a `double` to a function that expects a string to write into; this obviously won't work, you'll have to copy that piece of input string to a suitable buffer, and then parse it to a `double` (using e.g. `strtod`).

On a personal note, this is a quite serious mistake, you should really review your C manual before going further.

Comment: I'll look into this. Thank you! My professor told us to use this function without actually explaining how it worked. I am trying to figure out why its not working, unfortunately.

Answer (score -4):

You can use GDB to help you. For example, you program name demo.c

```
$ gcc -g -o demo demo.c
$ gdb demo

Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from demo...done.
(gdb)
```

And then, you can set some break points and use step or next to observe the memory.

Comment: If he cannot get it to compile, then he doesn't need GDB yet.